# How to find current upper Bollinger band in pandas-ta

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-ta

I have a CSV file having columns `Instrument, Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close` I want the rows having `Current close greater than current upper Bollinger band(20,2)` I found the function `bbands` in `pandas-ta` but I don't know how to compare it with Current close and how to find upper.
Below is the code that much I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
df = pd.read_csv("NIFTY.csv", parse_dates = [["Date", "Time"]], index_col=0)
currunt_close = df["Close"]
currunt_upper_bollinger_band = ta.bbands(df["Close"], length=20, std=2)
```

Comment: How to download your data to help you?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a4XxeIS5LcmB0Kq2H7zqAxJsso3YE1sn?usp=sharing i uploaded file and also task , I'm trying to complete task - 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this code instead:

```
currunt_close.ta.bbands(close='Close', length=20, std=2, append=True)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)  # show all columns
```

`BBU_20_2.0` is what you looking for!

Comment: Consider using the "code sample" mode for blocks of code and double backticks for inline code: `BBU_20_2.0`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).